# Ballerina VSCode plugin not working on Linux but on Windows when using SSH

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-vscode-plugin

I have a weird problem with the Ballerina VSCode plugin:

It doesn't work on my laptop running Manjaro and Ballerina 2201.8.0, it always shows the error `bal command _stderr: /bin/sh: line1: bal: command not found`. However, in zsh (no matter if using Gnome Terminal or the integrated VSCode terminal, the `bal` command works perfectly fine.

What's even weirder is that the Ballerina plugin works perfectly fine when I SSH into my laptop using VSCode on Windows 10.

The ballerina installation directory is `/home/matthes/.ballerina-swan-lake`.

```
$ bal home   
/home/matthes/.ballerina-swan-lake/distributions/ballerina-2201.8.0
$ which bal
/home/matthes/.ballerina-swan-lake/bin/bal
$ echo $BALLERINA_HOME
/home/matthes/.ballerina-swan-lake/distributions/ballerina-2201.8.0
```

I installed it via zip as described [here](https://ballerina.io/downloads/installation-options/#install-via-the-ballerina-language-zip-file)

I tried setting the Ballerina Home settings in VSCode to each of the three paths above but that didn't help either.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the Ballerina VS Code plugin is having trouble finding the Ballerina home directory path. You can try following these steps,

1. Ensure that the Ballerina Home directory path is set correctly in your user settings of the Ballerina VS Code plugin. The path should be as follows,

   `Home: /home/matthes/.ballerina-swan-lake/distributions/ballerina-2201.8.0`
2. Check whether you've enabled `Plugin-dev-mode` in the user settings

Comment: I tried the first one once more just to be sure, but it didn't work. I also tried enabling dev mode: While the home path was set, it led to the same error. After clearing the home path, it led to a different error: Failed to start Ballerina Plugin. 

Edit: With dev mode enabled and home path set, the error output is slightly different, it tells me that JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, which is weird because I think it's set correcly (to `/usr/lib/jvm/default`)

Comment: @matthesinator Now it seems that `JAVA_HOME` is not being picked up correctly for this particular terminal process. You can either try closing all instances of VS Code and reopening it, or restart your machine because sometimes environment variables may require a system restart to take full effect.

Comment: That sadly didn't work either. I also tried setting $JAVA_HOME explicitly to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk`, but that didn't help too

Comment: Update: As per [this](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/15726) github thread I started VS Code from a terminal, and all of sudden the plugin works! I'd still like to figure out why it doesn't work when I start it normally, but if that's not possible I can live with the workaround